# Eclipse Plugin - change code analysis preferences programmability

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, preferences, code-analysis

I'm writing a plugin for eclipse CDT on Windows.
I want to programmability go to the workspace preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Analysis -> Type cannot be resolved, and remove the V mark from this option. In other words, I want my plugin won't show errors when user will write code with unresolved types.

Do you know what is the way to do so?
any answer will be appreciated..

Comment: do you have any idea ?